# Enabling rapid, multiple taps on Safario in iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, fastclick.js

I'm using the Fastclick.js library to get rid of the 300ms delay in iOS Safari when pressing buttons and links.  It definitely removes the delay for one-off clicks, but I have an application where a user has to rapidly tap a button in the browser, and the button needs to click each time and run a script.  The button doesn't seem to register multiple quick taps in a row, only the first one.  I'm guessing this is because the system interprets the second tap as the end of a double tap.  Is there any way to deal with this situation?  I don't have this issue on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!  The concepts and (almost) complete code are provided here:

https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons

And then these guys took that code and put it into a nice javascript and jquery package:

https://github.com/msbit/google-fastbutton

You can even get it with `bower install google-fastbutton`.